# Передача парамметров в paint JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Есть массив значений(координат), как передать его в метод paint, чтобы он отрисовывал по этим координатам? Обычной передачей параметров нельзя сделать. Как это организовать?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class TestPaint extends JPanel {

  public void paint(Graphics g, int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        g.DrawLine(array[i], 100, array[i] + 100, 100);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i]=i*100;
    }


    JFrame window = new JFrame("text");
    window.setContentPane(d);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 900));
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Нужно сделать массив глобальным, а у тебя он живет локально внутри main()

Answer (score 1):

Через состояние объекта

```
class TestPaint extends JPanel {
  private int[] array;

  public TestPaint(int[] array) {
    this.array = array;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        g.DrawLine(array[i], 100, array[i] + 100, 100);
    }
}
```